# Do files in a quarto project render in alphabetical order by default?

Tags: quarto

I have a quarto project that contains a series of `.qmd` files that need to be rendered sequentially.

In order to make this happen I've been explicitly listing the files in order in `_quarto.yml`, like so:

```
render:
  - R/01_do-this-first.qmd
  - R/02_do-this-second.qmd
  - R/03_do-this-last.qmd
```

Is this really necessary, or will these files be rendered in order anyway on account of their alphabetically sequential filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Quarto does not guarantee alphabetical rendering order by default.

In [Control order of rendering](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6944) discussion developers confirm that alphabetical order is not default

> **My request is:** Please provide a way to control the rendering order of qmd files. Optimally that would not depend on filenames or titles, but e.g. on metadata like order, **but alphabetical file name order would be okay, too.**

it is necessary to list the files explicitly in `_quarto.yml` to  render files in their alphabetically sequential filenames order.

See [Render Targets](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/quarto-projects.html#render-targets) and [Control order of rendering](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6944) for more information